# MySQL Stored Procedure with Cursor - Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating this stored procedure, and I am getting a syntax error with the first select on the procedure. This procedure has an IN var called selProyecto.

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE num_clientes INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;       
   DECLARE nInicio DATE;
   DECLARE nFin DATE;
   DECLARE nIdCliente INT;
   DECLARE clientCounter INT;
   DECLARE auxDias INT;
   DECLARE finClientes BOOLEAN;
   DECLARE finContratos BOOLEAN;

   SELECT COUNT(clientes.id) from clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto INTO num_clientes;

   DECLARE clientes_proyecto CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto;

   -- Declaración de un manejador de error tipo NOT FOUND
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finClientes = TRUE;
   OPEN clientes_proyecto;
   loop_clientesProyecto: LOOP

    -- Recogemos la id del Cliente
    FETCH clientes_proyecto INTO nIdCliente;
    -- Reseteamos los días trabajados
    SET auxDias = 0;

    -- Abrimos un segundo cursor para iterar los contratos de ese cliente
    DECLARE cliContratos CURSOR FOR SELECT fecha_inicio, fecha_fin FROM contratos_cliente WHERE id_cliente = nIdCliente;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finContratos = TRUE;
    OPEN cliContratos;
    loop_contratos: LOOP
        FETCH cliContratos INTO nInicio, nFin;
        IF nFin < CURDATE() THEN
            auxDias = auxDias + Datediff(nInicio, nFin);
         ELSE
            auxDias = auxDias + Datediff(nInicio, CURDATE());
         END IF;
        IF finContratos THEN
            LEAVE loop_contratos;
        END IF;
    end loop_contratos;

    -- Ya tenemos los días trabajados del cliente, realizamos el cálculo del porcentaje
    SET @porcentaje = @porcentaje + ((((auxDias)/90)*(100/num_clientes))/100)

    IF finClientes THEN
        LEAVE loop_clientesProyecto;
    END IF;

   end loop_clientesProyecto;

END
```

The purpose is calculate a percent of the clients having worked 90 days, but cannot save it.

First I take the total number of clientes with `SELECT COUNT(clientes.id) from clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto INTO num_clientes;` then I declare a cursor to iterate each client. Inside the cursor I try to declare another cursor to take the total worked days for that client. At the end I calculate the percent of the worked days with a function.

The issue is that it throws a syntax error just before the first select.

I have tryied to change the sentence for: `SET num_clientes = (SELECT COUNT(clientes.id) from clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto);` with the same result

Comment: what is the syntax error?

Comment: I am doing in phpMyAdmin, it says `You have an syntax error near "DECLARE clientes_proyecto CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto;"`

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be here:

`DECLARE clientes_proyecto CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto`

You are referencing `selProyecto` before it is defined.

Update: Here's a similar example on my server:

```
mysql> DECLARE foo CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM mysql.user WHERE id = bar;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE foo CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM mysql.user WHERE id = bar' at line 1
```

Comment: selProyecto is an IN var on the procedure. Sorry for not commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled myself. Here is the code:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE num_clientes INT DEFAULT 0;      
   DECLARE nInicio DATE;
   DECLARE nFin DATE;
   DECLARE nIdCliente INT;
   DECLARE clientCounter INT;
   DECLARE auxDias INT;
   DECLARE finClientes BOOLEAN;
   DECLARE finContratos BOOLEAN;
   DECLARE porcentaje DOUBLE;
   DECLARE clientes_proyecto CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finClientes = TRUE;

   SET num_clientes = (SELECT COUNT(clientes.id) from clientes WHERE id_proyecto = selProyecto);



   -- Declaración de un manejador de error tipo NOT FOUND

   OPEN clientes_proyecto;
   loop_clientesProyecto: LOOP

    -- Recogemos la id del Cliente
    FETCH clientes_proyecto INTO nIdCliente;
    -- Reseteamos los días trabajados
    SET auxDias = 0;

    BLOCK2: BEGIN
    DECLARE cliContratos CURSOR FOR SELECT fecha_inicio, fecha_fin FROM contratos_clientes WHERE id_cliente = nIdCliente;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finContratos = TRUE;
    -- Abrimos un segundo cursor para iterar los contratos de ese cliente
    OPEN cliContratos;
    loop_contratos: LOOP
        FETCH cliContratos INTO nInicio, nFin;
        IF nFin < CURDATE() THEN
            SET auxDias = auxDias + Datediff(nInicio, nFin);
         ELSE
            SET auxDias = auxDias + Datediff(nInicio, CURDATE());
         END IF;
        IF finContratos THEN
            LEAVE loop_contratos;
        END IF;
    END LOOP loop_contratos;
    CLOSE cliContratos;
    END BLOCK2;

    -- Ya tenemos los días trabajados del cliente, realizamos el cálculo del porcentaje
    SET porcentaje = porcentaje + ((((auxDias)/90)*(100/num_clientes))/100);

    IF finClientes THEN
        LEAVE loop_clientesProyecto;
    END IF;

   END LOOP loop_clientesProyecto;
   CLOSE clientes_proyecto;

   SELECT porcentaje;

END
```

As you can see for nested CURSORS we have to define the first in the DECLARE section, then declare the handler. Inside the LOOP we have to define a new BLOCK and do the next CURSOR LOOP.